# Classification tolerance

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am now doing a classification task that I want to classify data into three security group, including A, B and C.

I wonder that is there any word can describe the following situation.

The situation is that Group A have higher security level than Group B,
so it is unacceptable if data belong to Group A is classified as Group B.
But, it is tolerable if data belong to Group B  is classified as Group A.

I want to find some keywords to describe this situation,any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your case study is to give a **penelized weight** when your model misclassify A as B . this case is a same as if you have unbalanced dataset where the negative class is Overrepresented, so to dead with that we add a weight to the positive class.

Your case is particular, you want only to give a wight > 1 if class A is predicted as B. your confusion matrix should be as bellow where your add a weight W.

`|                   | real class A | real class B | real class C |
 |-------------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
 | predicted class A | v1           | W * v2       | v3           |
 | predicted class B | v4           | v5           | v6           |
 | predicted class C | v7           | v8           | v9           |`

keyworks: weighted classification, penalized log loss or classification

Hope that will help